# Click on custom button opens modal window

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, mvc, modal

I've got some custom buttons in my Joomla component and I want them to open in a modal window like with the batch button in the com_content component. Anyone has got any idea on how to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple.

In **view.html.php**, load modal library, if it's not already done:

```
JHtml::_('bootstrap.modal');
```

For adding button to toolbar, use:

```
// Toolbar object
$toolbar = JToolBar::getInstance('toolbar');
$layout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.toolbar.popup');

// Render the popup button
$dhtml = $layout->render(array('name' => 'test', 'text' => JText::_('Custom button'), 'class' => 'icon-archive', 'doTask' => ''));
$toolbar->appendButton('Custom', $dhtml);
```

`name` must match modal `id` after `-`. You can change `class` for different icons.

In **default.php** or in any file in `tmpl` folder add modal div, what will be shown after clicking on link

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="modal-test">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" role="presentation" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
    <h3>Modal title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Modal content here
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">
      <?php echo JText::_('JCANCEL'); ?>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: would this also work if the button is inside of the toolbar? Because right now I create my custom toolbar button with JToolbarHelper::custom inside of view.html.php. I'm sorry I wasn't clear in my post

Comment: @republicca I edited my answer for adding button to toolbar.

Comment: Do you know how to apply a form.xml file to this modal windows?

Comment: Yes. You just have to load new `JForm` in your `view.html.php` and then print it in modal. I can see you have posted [new question](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/12125/jform-in-modal-window) for this. But I would create new view what and then load that into modal with AJAX. See example JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/NUCgp/918/).

Comment: and how do you tell the custom button to go to the new view?  What do I have to add to this line to href to the new modal view? `$dhtml = $layout->render(array('name' => 'newbook', 'text' => JText::_('New book'), 'class' => 'icon-new');`

Comment: Answered in your new question.

Comment: There is a small issue with the above solution. There is a parameter missing in the array passed to `$layout->render()`. The `doTask` parameter must be set. The value set will be put into the button's `value` attribute. If you don't want a value, simply set it to a blank string. Without `doTask`, PHP will show a notice that reads 'Notice: Undefined index: doTask in /path_to_my_site/layouts/joomla/toolbar/popup.php on line 14'. This works great. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Thanks @ZacharyDraper, added `doTask` to avoid notice.